# Exclude everything staring with dot in lftp mirror command

Tags: regex, bash, lftp

I'm using [LFTP](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) to mirror some Git files to my server from a Docker image using a CI/CD Pipeline vendor. This works as expected but when using the `mirror` command from LFTP, I need to exclude any kind of file starting with a dot, like so:

```sh
lftp -u $USERNAME, -e "[...] mirror [...] --ignore-time -x '/(\.\w*.*)/$' --exclude README.md [...]; exit" sftp://$HOST
```

But none of those are working, it just *jumps out* that `-x` command and goes for the next one (e.g. `--exclude README.md`).

I guess is not about using `-x` or `--exclude` since, from [the docs](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html):

> **mirror** [*OPTS*] [*source* [*target*]]
>
> [...]
>
> -x RX, --exclude=RX exclude matching files

This ones didn't work either:

```regex
-x '/(\.\w*.*)/$'
```

```regex
-x /(\.\w*.*)/$
```

```regex
-x /(\.\w*.*)/
```

```regex
-x (\.\w*.*)
```

```regex
-x \.\w*.*
```

What is wrong then? Isn't that a valid regex for **Bash**?

Comment: best I can tell from your code it's not bash that's trying to understand your regexp its `mirror`. idk about lftp specifically but very few tools will understand `\w` in a regexp. If you're trying to represent "word constituent characters" with `\w` then try replacing it with the POSIX `[[:alnum:]_]` instead, e.g. `-x '^\.[[:alnum:]_]*'`, but that's probably not necessary anyway since the regexp to match any string starting with a `.` is just `^\.`.

Comment: This is your regex `\.` it matches the first dot it finds, doesn't matter where it is. If you want to only match at the beginning or spaces then dot, use `^\s*\.` or `^[ \t]*\.`

Comment: @EdMorton Almost. The regexp to match any string starting with a `.` is `^\..*`, because `^\.` would only match the dot itself. I hope this doesn't sound like nitpicking, but it is a difference.

Comment: @mumpitz in the context of strings, `.` is a string and that string starts with `.`.

Comment: But that's not *any* string starting with `.`. It's just `.`. Anyway, I just wanted to be precise here - it's independent from the context of this question, so yeah, my bad. I just see many people getting confused because a regexp like `^\.` doesn't match their string `.foo`.

Comment: @mumpitz Oh I get where you're coming from now. To use `grep` as an example, I was thinking of `grep '\.'` vs `grep '\..*'` while you're thinking of `grep -o '\.' file` vs `grep -o '\..*'`. Understood.

Comment: For some reason none of those regex could make it work using `ls -latr | grep '...'`, I need to exclude `.git` (and the content), `.editorconfig`, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm happy we sorted that out - I started feeling like a pedantic pest.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro why not try what I suggested: `ls -latr | grep -v '^\.'`? Obviously if you were really using `ls` you just wouldn't include the `a` arg so `ls` wouldn't output the `.` files in the first place.

Comment: @EdMorton You're totally right hahaha Anyway, `--exclude '^\..*$'` worked for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the only way that worked for me is to use `$` at the end of the `--exclude` regex, like so:

```
lftp -u $USERNAME, -e "[...] mirror [...] --exclude '^\..*$'[...]
```

**Without the end-of-line delimiter it seems to not work at all**, just ignores that `--exclude` or `-x` option and goes for the next one . Also, **the regex must be wrapped in quotation marks** (single or double).

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to use -X option like this:
     -X .* -X .*/